# Uninstalling a plugin: delete all options with specific prefix

Tags: php, plugin-development, uninstallation

#### Objective

As all plugin developer, I want to delete all options that begin with the same prefix.

#### Backstory

I've developed a plugin that stores data in the options. When the user uninstalls the plugin, the `uninstall.php` in the plugin executes the following code:

```
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
    exit;
}

delete_option( 'myplugin_some_opt_1' );
delete_option( 'myplugin_some_opt_2' );
delete_option( 'myplugin_some_opt_3' );
delete_option( 'myplugin_some_opt_4' );
```

Since all of the options start with `myplugin_`, I want to implement a wildcard. Logicall, I assume that it would look something like this:

```
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
    exit;
}

delete_option( 'myplugin_*' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out another alternative by using the [`wp_load_alloptions()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_load_alloptions) function to get all of the available options, then `delete_option()` for every option that has the `myplugin_` prefix:

```
foreach ( wp_load_alloptions() as $option => $value ) {
    if ( strpos( $option, 'myplugin_' ) === 0 ) {
        delete_option( $option );
    }
}
```

Comment: works only for autoloaded options

Answer (score 8):

Replace "myplugin_" with your prefix:

```
global $wpdb;

$plugin_options = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_name FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE 'myplugin_%'" );

foreach( $plugin_options as $option ) {
    delete_option( $option->option_name );
}
```